# How to use a method from another file inside of a function that's inside a class

Tags: python, django

I'm supposed to get the name and last name of the person that writes their id in a form I wrote. To get the name and last name I was given a function that I'm supposed to use but I don't know how to use it. Where do I call for it and when?

This is the file x.py that I have to use:

```
def get_persona(id_requested, ta_sign=None, ta_token=None):
    try:
        if ta_sign is None and ta_token is None:
            ta_sign, ta_token = wsaa.get_ta_sign_token('a13')
        client = Client(13_wsdl)
        response = client.service.getPersona(
            sign=ta_sign,
            token=ta_token,
            cuitRepresentada=id_consultante,
            idPersona=id_requested,
        )
        return serialize_object(response, target_cls=dict)
    except Fault as e:
        if e.message == 'No person with Id':
            return None
        elif e.message == 'Inactive person':
            return 'Inactive'
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None
```

This is my view so far:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views import View
from .forms import MonotributoForm
from .x import get_persona

class ConstanciaInscripcion(View):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
    
    def post(self,request):

        if request:

            form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
            
            get_persona(id_requested)
                    

            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data.get('id')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                cuit.save()
                email.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
        else:
             pass # could add a notification here
        
        return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

Comment: What do all the `from` statements at the top of your view do?

Comment: @RazzleShazl Oh the first one is for the render and then to import the view of the class and the form from the form and the last one is to import the function from another file

Comment: You have to feed get_persona an ID.  Do you have an ID?  I don't see it.  We can't tell what object the getPersona request returns, so we can't advise you on that.  It looks like it returns a dict, so I'm guessing that dict has keys with the information you need.

Comment: try giving full path once

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh I modified the name but now the id is there (it's part of the form). I'm not sure where I'd have to write that for it to work.

Comment: @daneilJames The full path of what?

Comment: from app_path->.file_path-> import -> your_function

Comment: So, you're now fetching the ID and passing it to get_persona?  And does it work now?